# Best way for implement 'Site Gate'

Tags: 6, users, redirection, cookies, sessions

I try to add 'site gate' to http://bartenderlab.it. 
It's alcohol content so people under 18 are not allowed to view this site.

I created module with hook_init:

```
function gate_init() {

    $curr_uri = request_uri():
    if (strpos($curr_uri, '/gate') === FALSE) {

        if (! isset($_SESSION[GATE_SESSION_NAME])) {

            if (! isset($_COOKIE[GATE_COOKIE_NAME])) {

                    if(strlen($curr_uri) > 1) {

                        drupal_goto('gate', array('destination' => substr($curr_uri, 1)));

                    }
                    drupal_goto('gate');    

            } else {

                $_SESSION[GATE_SESSION_NAME] = TRUE;

            }
        } 
    } else if(isset($_SESSION[GATE_SESSION_NAME])) {

        drupal_goto('<front>');

    } 
}
```

Under /gate url is form with:

```
function gate_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state) {

    $post = $form_state['values'];
    $day = intval($post['gate_day']);
    $month = intval($post['gate_month']); 
    $year = intval($post['gate_year']);
    $isRemember = $post['gate_remember_me'];
    if($day && $month && $year) {

        $allowed_age = (int) variable_get('gate_minimal_age', 18);
        $min_born_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y") - $allowed_age);
        $born_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);

        if($min_born_time >= $born_time) {

            $_SESSION[GATE_SESSION_NAME] = TRUE;
            if($isRemember) {

                setcookie(GATE_COOKIE_NAME, sha1($born_time + srand()), time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/');

            } 
            $dst = '<front>';

            if(isset($_GET['destination'])) {

                $dst = $_GET['destination'];

            }

            drupal_goto($dst);
        }
    } 
}
```

If checkbox for $isRemember is not checked user should only view site until browser close.

so I set:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  0);
```

in settings.php

But after restart browser gate page doesn't appear.

Also after user logout I am redirect to gate page instead of front page.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Disclaimer](http://drupal.org/project/disclaimer) module; it seems to be the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The nice code I have which work is:

```
function gate_init() {
    global $user;

    $curr_uri = request_uri(); 
    $request_type = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], ','));

    if($request_type == 'text/html') {

        // check if the user is going to logout and have gate enabled
        if($curr_uri == '/' && $user->session == '' && isset($_COOKIE['keep_logged_in']) && $_COOKIE['keep_logged_in'] == 1) {
            _gate_allow_entrance();
            setcookie('keep_logged_in', '', time() - 42000, '/');
        }

        // maybe they have cookie set before
        if(isset($_COOKIE[GATE_COOKIE_NAME]) && $_COOKIE[GATE_COOKIE_NAME] == TRUE && !isset($_SESSION[GATE_SESSION_NAME]))
            _gate_allow_entrance();

        if($curr_uri != GATE_URL) {
            if(!(isset($_SESSION[GATE_SESSION_NAME]) && $_SESSION[GATE_SESSION_NAME] === TRUE))
                drupal_goto('gate');
        }

        // if there is a gate key and logout was called, then keep the key within next request
        if($curr_uri == '/logout' && isset($_SESSION[GATE_SESSION_NAME]) && $_SESSION[GATE_SESSION_NAME] === TRUE)
            setcookie('keep_logged_in', 1, time() + 10, '/'); // only for 10 seconds

    }

    return true;
}
```